# SQL - Aggregated Functions - Misuse of COUNT Function

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table that contains songs ("Tracks" is the name of my table). I can only use this table to retrieve my data.

The table contains a column with the AlbumId. So I am trying to find all the albums in this table that have at least 12 songs.

I use the below code but I get an error message (misuse of aggregate: COUNT()

```
SELECT 
AlbumId,
COUNT(*)
FROM Tracks
WHERE COUNT(*) > 12
GROUP BY AlbumId;
```

What exactly is wrong with my code and how would I be able to get the data that I want?

Thanks!

Comment: `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT()`, second to filter by aggregate you need to use `HAVING` instead of  `WHERE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct SQL you need here is `SELECT AlbumId, COUNT(TrackID) AS tracks FROM Tracks GROUP BY AlbumID HAVING COUNT(TrackID) > 12;`

> WHY use ***HAVING*** ??

Because you need to apply the condition of *having more than 12 tracks* **after** you group by AlbumID.